# When is exponentiation a bijection $\mod{p}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

I thought about this question while solving a maths problem. Essentially, it came down to showing that if $a\in \{1, 2, 3... p-1\}$ then the set of all residues of $a$ $\mod{29}$ was equal to the set of all residues of $a^5 \mod{29}$. So I'm wondering when this is generally true, where the set of all residues of $a$ $\mod{p}$ is equal to the set of all residues of $a^n \mod{p}$.

I apologize in advance for misused terminology!

Comment: You may have a look at [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n). I'm actually not quite sure whether this is what you want. It may also be simply the fact that $\gcd(5, 28) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful!

Comment: Indeed, this is true precisely when $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$. To see that this condition is sufficient at least, note that when $\gcd(n,p-1)=1$ there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $mn\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$, and then note that $a\mapsto a^n\pmod p$ and $b\mapsto b^m\pmod p$ are inverses of each other by Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @GregMartin I'd expect that anyone familiar with Fermat's little theorem would know about the bijection mentioned by the OP

Comment: @PM2Ring Sure, but OP doesn't seem to know it. :)